# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _FILES in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\user\utils\CommonUtils.php on line 1395

The code on line 1395 is

```
public static function saveAvatar($code, $pilotid, $_FILES) {
```

Comment: I've removed the mysql tag. Please note that tags are supposed to describe your question, not your project.

Answer (score 11):

you can't use `$_FILES` for function parameter it's reserved word, use this instead of

```
public static function saveAvatar($code, $pilotid, $files) { }
```

and for calling pass the `$_FILES` like this

```
saveAvatar($code, $pilotid, $_FILES);
```

**OR**

You can also directly access the `$_FILES` without passing it in function parameter inside function.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to set a variable called $_FILES in local scpe as an argument to the saveAvatar() method; but can't because it's one of the special superglobals.

Change the line to

```
public static function saveAvatar($code, $pilotid) {
```

The $_FILES superglobal will still be available to that method simply because it is a superglobal

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. Then I just removed the $_FILES variable from list of variables and my website started working again.

Comment: Thank-you style answers which just repeat an already posted answer are not suited for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we can't reassign the $_Files, which means we can't pass the auto super global variable as argument -or function. But we have an alternate solutions.

Pass the file as parameter

```
  function ImageProcess(array $_File){
           $image        = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
           $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
           //Write your code here...
  }
```

Call the function with auto global-variable as argument.

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
      if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
         echo ImageProcess($_FILES['file']);
      }
  }
```

Form for upload

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="file" /> 
       <button type="submit">Update &amp; Save</button>
    </form>
```