# Paypal - Store values and save after transaction is processed

Tags: php, paypal

Plan:

1. Fill in table
2. Values are stored in a session
3. Process transaction
4. If transation is completed, values get stored in database.
5. else values are not stored.

How can I fix the code in insertdata.php (last block of code) so as the errors are removed?

The form 
http://jsfiddle.net/christa_mar/b7xpkk2p/1/

**payments.php**

```
<?php

 if ($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['proceedtopaypal'])){
    session_start();

include 'connect.php';

    $_SESSION['apartment'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['apartment']);
    $_SESSION['unitprice'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['unitprice']);
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first_name']);
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_name']);
    $_SESSION['payer_email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['payer_email']);
    $_SESSION['address'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $_SESSION['apt_name'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['apt_name']);
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobile']);
    $_SESSION['pax'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pax']);
    $_SESSION['remarks'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['remarks']);
    $_SESSION['day_from'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day_from']);
    $_SESSION['month_from'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['month_from']);
    $_SESSION['year_from'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['year_from']);
    $_SESSION['booking_from'] = $_SESSION['year_from']."-".$_SESSION['month_from']."-".$_SESSION['day_from'];
    $_SESSION['day_to'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day_to']);
    $_SESSION['month_to'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['month_to']);
    $_SESSION['year_to'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['year_to']);
    $_SESSION['booking_to'] = $_SESSION['year_to']."-".$_SESSION['month_to'] ."-".$_SESSION['day_to'];
    $_SESSION['no_of_nights'] = abs(strtotime($_SESSION['booking_from']) - strtotime($_SESSION['booking_to'])); 
    $_SESSION['quantity'] = floor($_SESSION['no_of_nights'] / (60*60*24));

    // paypal settings 
    $paypal_email = 'christabelbusuttil-facilitator@gmail.com';
    $return_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/apartment-details.php?id=1';
    $cancel_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/apartment-details.php?id=1';
    $notify_url = 'http://localhost/Webdevelopment/V18/paypal/payments.php';

    $item_amount = $_SESSION['unitprice'] * $_SESSION['quantity'];
    $item_name = "Booking at ".$_SESSION['apt_name']." from " .$_SESSION['booking_from'] ." to " .$_SESSION['booking_to'];
    $validdate = false;
    $buttonpressed = false;
    $checkin='<p>Check in date is invalid.</p>';
    $checkout='<p>Check out date is invalid</p>';
    $larger = '<p>Check in date is after check out date</p>';
    $noinfo='<p>please fill in the missing information.</p>';
    $booked='<p>The dates selected are already booked for this apartment</p>';
    $equal = '<p>You need to spend a minimum of 1 night in these apartment</p>';
    $thankyou = '<h5>Thank you</h5><p>thank you for booking an apartment with V18-apartments.</p>';
    $window = '';

        function IsInjected($str) {
          $injections = array('(\n+)',
                      '(\r+)',
                      '(\t+)',
                      '(%0A+)',
                      '(%0D+)',
                      '(%08+)',
                      '(%09+)'
                      );
          $inject = join('|', $injections);
          $inject = "/$inject/i";
          if(preg_match($inject,$str))
            {
            return true;
          }
          else
            {
            return false;
            }
        }

        if (!checkdate($_SESSION['month_from'], $_SESSION['day_from'], $_SESSION['year_from'])) {
            $window = $checkin;
            echo $window;
            $validate = true;
        }
        if (!checkdate($_SESSION['month_to'], $_SESSION['day_to'], $_SESSION['year_to'])) {
            $window = $checkout;
            $validate = true;
            echo $window;
            //echo "Check out date is invalid";
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['booking_from'] > $_SESSION['booking_to']) {
                $window = $larger;
                $validate = true;
                echo $window;
                // echo "Check in date is after check out date";
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['booking_from'] == $_SESSION['booking_to']) {
            $window = $equal;
            $validate = true;
            echo $window;
        }   
    // check if all info is filled in 
        else if (($_SESSION['first_name'] == "Name") || ($_SESSION['last_name'] == "surname") || ($_SESSION['payer_email'] == "Email") || ($_SESSION['mobile'] == "mobile") || ($_SESSION['address'] == "Address")) {
            $window = $noinfo;
            echo $window;
            $validate = true;
            // echo "Please fill in the missing information";
        }
        else if (IsInjected($payer_email)) {
            echo "Not an email";
        }
        else if ($validdate == false) {
            $final = true;
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM room_nights WHERE apartmentID= '$apartment' AND dates >= '$booking_from' AND dates <= '$booking_to'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            if ($row[0] > 0) {
                $window = $booked;
                echo $window;
            }

        else if ($final == true)  {
            // save to database 
            //  include 'insertdata.php';

                echo $item_name;
                // include functions
                include ("pay_functions.php");
                // Check if paypal request or response
                if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
                // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
                    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";  
                    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html
                    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
                    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
                    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
                        //loop for posted values and append to querystring
                        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                            $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
                        }
                    // Append paypal return addresses
                    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
                    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
                    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);
                    // Append querystring with custom field
                    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;
                    // Redirect to paypal IPN
                    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
                    exit();

                } 
            else {
                    // Response from paypal
                    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
                        $req .= "&$key=$value";
                    }

                    // assign posted variables to locate variables
                    $data['item_name'] = $_POST['item_name'];
                    $data['item_number'] = $_POST['item_number'];
                    $data['payment_status'] = $_POST['payment_status'];
                    $data['payment_amount'] = $_POST['mc_gross'];
                    $data['payment_currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
                    $data['txn_id'] = $_POST['txn_id'];
                    $data['receiver_email'] = $_POST['receiver_email'];
                    $data['payer_email'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
                    $data['custom'] = $_POST['custom'];

                    // post back to paypal system and validate

                    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                    $header .= "Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
                    $header .= "Content-Lenght: " .strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

                    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

                if (!$fp) {
                // HTTP error
                } else {
                    mail('christabelbusuttil@gmail.com', '0', '0');
                    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
                    while (!feof($fp)) {
                        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
                        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                             // validate payment (check unique txnid & correct price) 
                             $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                             $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                             // Payment validated and verified
                            if ($valid_price && $valid_price) {
                                 $orderid = updatePayments($data);
                                if ($orderid){
                                     // payment has been made and inserted into db
                                } else {
                                     echo "Error";
                                }
                            } 
                            else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                                    echo "Payment invalid";
                            }
                        }
                             fclose($fp);
                    }
                }
            }    
        } 
    } 
}

}

?>
```

Then if `payment_status = complete` -> use the data stored in the session and save to database.  OR discard if not complete.

```
  $payment_status  = isset($_POST['payment_status']) ?    $_POST['payment_status'] : '';
 if ($payment_status == 'Completed') {
session_start();
 // Echo Value for testing purposes
echo "Apartment Value is " . $_SESSION['apartment'] . " - " .$apartment . "<br>";
echo "Unit Price is " . $_SESSION['unitprice'] ."<br>";
echo "First Name is " . $_SESSION['first_name'] ."<br>";
echo "Last Name is " . $_SESSION['last_name'] ."<br>";
echo "Payer Email is " .$_SESSION['payer_email'] ."<br>";
echo "Address is " . $_SESSION['address']."<br>";
echo "Apartment Name is " . $_SESSION['apt_name'] ."<br>";
echo "Mobile number is " .$_SESSION['mobile'] ."<br>";
echo "Number of people" .$_SESSION['pax'] ."<br>";
echo "Remarks " . $_SESSION['remarks'] ."<br>";
echo "Booking From "  .$_SESSION['booking_from'] ."<br>";
echo "Booking To " .$_SESSION['booking_to'] ."<br>";
echo "Number of Nights ". $_SESSION['no_of_nights'] ."<br>";
echo "Quantity " .$_SESSION['quantity'] ."<br>";
$reason = "Booked by ".$_SESSION['first_name']." ".$_SESSION['last_name']." for ".$_SESSION['pax'] ." people";

    $fullname = $_SESSION['first_name'] ." ".$_SESSION['last_name'];

    echo $reason ."<br>";
    echo $fullname ."<br>";

include 'insertdata.php';

echo "Payment Completed";
session_unset();

// destroy the session
session_destroy(); 
}
else {

}
```

**insertdata.php**

```
 <?php

function daterange($_SESSION['booking_from'], $_SESSION['booking_to'], $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = new DateTime($_SESSION['booking_from']);
  $last = new DateTime($_SESSION['booking_to']);
  $last = $last->modify('+ 1 day');
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
  $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);


  foreach ($period as $date) {
      $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  } 

  return $dates;
}

$dates = daterange($_SESSION['booking_from'], $_SESSION['booking_to']);

print_r($dates);

 include 'connect.php';

 if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', '$fullname', $_SESSION['payer_email'], $_SESSION['address'], $_SESSION['mobile'])")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }


 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '$apartment', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$quantity', '$pax', '$remarks')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 foreach ($dates as $date) {
 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, dates, reason) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$date', '$reason')")) {
      printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 } 
 }

 if (!$conn->commit()) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 $conn->close();

 ?>
```

> Error: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\V18\insertdata.php on line 3

Comment: You are not stating any problem whatsoever. Can you formulate why you need help ?

Comment: Updated question to give it more sense.

Comment: How can you hope anyone help you if you have posted almost all application? Why don't you isolated your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
function daterange($_SESSION['booking_from'], $_SESSION['booking_to'], $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = new DateTime($_SESSION['booking_from']);
  $last = new DateTime($_SESSION['booking_to']);
  $last = $last->modify('+ 1 day');
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
  $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);


  foreach ($period as $date) {
      $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  } 

  return $dates;
}
```

When you are writing this function you are trying to overwrite the $_SESSION array, you cannot do this, instead of doing that try using a variable name like `$booking_from`, etc. then pass in the values that you want to use in the function.
See this other question:[Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954446/fatal-error-cannot-re-assign-auto-global-variable)